# Regular Expressions for ASTM Protocol String

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

What can be the Regular Expression for ASTM Standard protocol String?

```
"P|1||123456||^|||U" + ProtocolASCII.LF
   + "O|1||138||||||||||||O" + ProtocolASCII.LF
   + "R|1|^^^BE(B)||mmol/L||C||||||20150819144937" + ProtocolASCII.LF
   + "R|2|^^^BEecf||mmol/L||C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
   + "R|3|^^^Ca++|1.17|mmol/L" + ProtocolASCII.LF
```

Where `ProtocolASCII.LF = '\n'`. I am writing String *parser* to extract data from this String.

I have splited String based on `\n` and now I need to parse each String to extract data.

Is there any Regular Expression so that I can map to and get desired result?

The String `P|1||123456||^|||U" + ProtocolASCII.LF` present patient number where **P** means patient tag or patient information and **123456** is patient number.

For String `R|3|^^^Ca++|1.17|mmol/L" + ProtocolASCII.LF` is the result of laboratory test performed. Where **R** indicated *result*, **^^^Ca++** indicates name of the result, **1.17** is result value and **mmol/L** is unit.

Currently I am parsing String like:

```
String[] resultArray = dataString.split("[\\r\\n]+");

    HashMap<String, Object> resultData = new HashMap<>();
    List<Result> sampleResults = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String res : resultArray) {
        //Get first character of String 
        char startChar = res.charAt(0);
        switch (startChar) {
            case ProtocolASCII.STX:
                //Handle Header information. This is special case
                if (res.charAt(2) == ProtocolASCII.Alphabet.H
                        || res.charAt(1) == ProtocolASCII.Alphabet.H) {
                    resultData.put(Key.MACHINE_INFO, getHeaderInfo(res));
                    //System.out.println(res.charAt(2));           
                }
                break;
            case ProtocolASCII.Alphabet.P:
                resultData.put(Key.PATIENT, getPatientInfo(res));
                break;
            case ProtocolASCII.Alphabet.O:
                resultData.put(Key.ORDER, getOrderInfo(res));
                break;
            case ProtocolASCII.Alphabet.R:
                sampleResults.add(getResultInfo(res));
                break;
            case ProtocolASCII.Alphabet.L:
                // TODO - Handle end of line
                break;
        }
    }
```

This is my complete ASTM Protocol String:

```
/**
 * Sample string
 */
public static final String MACHINE_STRING_ASTM = ProtocolASCII.STX + "1H|\\^&|||GEM 3000^5.6.1     ^21152^^023665^2.4|||||||||20150819154754" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "P|1||322061||^|||U" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "O|1||138||||||||||||O" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|1|^^^BE(B)||mmol/L||C||||||20150819144937" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|2|^^^BEecf||mmol/L||C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|3|^^^Ca++|1.17|mmol/L" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|4|^^^Ca++(7.4)||mmol/L||C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|5|^^^HCO23-||mmol/L||C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|6|^^^HCO3std||mmol/L||C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|7|^^^K+|5.0|mmol/L" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|8|^^^Na+|140|mmol/L" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|9|^^^SO2c||%||C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|10|^^^TCO2||mmol/L||C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|11|^^^THbc||g/dL||C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "R|12|^^^Temp|37.0|C" + ProtocolASCII.LF
        + "L|1" + ProtocolASCII.EOT;
```

Is there a way I can extract data using [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Let me know if further information is required.

Thanks

Comment: Give us a clear picture , what do you want to get from the lines when it starts with P,R,O,L respectively ... then may not have to understand ASTM protocol but give you a solution ... say , if the line starts with P what do you want to parse for the rest of line, and same for R, O, L

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt I have mentioned in question as well! If it starts with **R**, we need to get the values except **|**, because it is separator. Example, R|3| is the test result of chemical component **Ca++** having value **1.17** with unit **mmol/L**. So, whenever R|n| comes, I need to have this data extracted. Note that R|4| has all these things except value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for R and P:

```
(?:^(R)\|(\d+)\|\^*([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|(?:([^|]*)\|)?.*$)|(?:^(P)\|(\d+)\|\|(\d+).*$)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nPPWv4/6)

Try this:

```
final String regex = "(?:^(R)\\|(\\d+)\\|\\^*([^|]*)\\|([^|]*)\\|(?:([^|]*)\\|)?.*$)|(?:^(P)\\|(\\d+)\\|\\|(\\d+).*$)";
final String string = "P|1||322061||^|||U \n"
     + "O|1||138||||||||||||O \n"
     + "R|1|^^^BE(B)||mmol/L||C||||||20150819144937 \n"
     + "R|2|^^^BEecf||mmol/L||C \n"
     + "R|3|^^^Ca++|1.17|mmol/L \n"
     + "R|4|^^^Ca++(7.4)||mmol/L||C \n"
     + "R|5|^^^HCO23-||mmol/L||C \n"
     + "R|6|^^^HCO3std||mmol/L||C \n"
     + "R|7|^^^K+|5.0|mmol/L \n"
     + "R|8|^^^Na+|140|mmol/L \n"
     + "R|9|^^^SO2c||%||C \n"
     + "R|10|^^^TCO2||mmol/L||C \n"
     + "R|11|^^^THbc||g/dL||C \n"
     + "R|12|^^^Temp|37.0|C\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    //System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

    if(matcher.group(1)!=null && matcher.group(1).equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
    {
        System.out.println("Result NO:"+matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("Component:"+matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println("value:"+matcher.group(4));
        System.out.println("unit:"+matcher.group(5));

        System.out.println("##############################");
    }
    else if(matcher.group(6)!=null && matcher.group(6).equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
    {
        System.out.println("Patient :"+matcher.group(7));
        System.out.println("Patient Number:"+matcher.group(8));

        System.out.println("##############################");
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Patient :1
Patient Number:322061
##############################
Result NO:1
Component:BE(B)
value:
unit:mmol/L
##############################
Result NO:2
Component:BEecf
value:
unit:mmol/L
##############################
Result NO:3
Component:Ca++
value:1.17
unit:mmol/L 
R
##############################
Result NO:5
Component:HCO23-
value:
unit:mmol/L
##############################
Result NO:6
Component:HCO3std
value:
unit:mmol/L
##############################
Result NO:7
Component:K+
value:5.0
unit:mmol/L 
R
##############################
Result NO:9
Component:SO2c
value:
unit:%
##############################
Result NO:10
Component:TCO2
value:
unit:mmol/L
##############################
Result NO:11
Component:THbc
value:
unit:g/dL
##############################
Result NO:12
Component:Temp
value:37.0
unit:null
##############################
```

Comment: Wow! This is just an awesome. I was struggling for couple of days. Just a minor change. As you can see some of the components have caps(^) character, this is optional, or it can occur or not in the string. Can you modify regex to accept Component like ^^^Ca++ and without cap characters, i.e Ca++ ?

Comment: Yeah, It can be the part of String or not but if it occurs, it must be with Component like ^^^K+

Comment: Ok, ^ is being optionalized , try now